# Copying and applying retention labels in sharepoint using C# script

Tags: development

I've got to transfer retention labels from one structure to another (same structure of directories) in Sharepoint. I've done a lot of research but I'm unable to find any solution for C# script code, could anyone point me in right direction or provide some documentation please?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @CallumCrowley SharePoint Online